# in my react-node app, node server crashes at post requests to a certain endpoint

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, react-fullstack

the server crashes when I attempt to make a POST request to 'http://localhost:5000/homepage/grab-repo'
hen i make a GET request to the same endpoint - it works well, but fails immediately at POST request

RepositoryDownload.js

```
        import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './repositorydownload.css';

function RepositoryDownload() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("ready to fetch?")
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/homepage/grab-repo', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ url })
    });
    console.log('response: ' + response);
    const data = await response.json();    
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("repo downloaded successfully!");

      // Handle the data returned from the server 

    } else {
      console.log("problem with grabbing repo!");
      throw new Error(data.message);
    }
  };
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setUrl(event.target.value);
  };

... returns...

export default RepositoryDownload;
```

homePageRouter.js

```
const express = require('express');
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const { grabAndSaveRepository } = require('../controllers/grabRepoController');
const homePageRouter = express.Router();

homePageRouter.get("/", auth, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Welcome  ")
  res.status(200).send("Welcome  ");
});

homePageRouter.get("/grab-repo", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("grab-repo endpoint works!");
});
// Handle POST request for form submission
homePageRouter.post('/grab-repo', grabAndSaveRepository);

module.exports = homePageRouter;
```

Thanx for help !